PWA Studio showing {{#pageTypeNonce}}{{#webpackChunks}}{{/webpackChunks}} {{/pageTypeNonce}} below footer with build without upward
The content is loading, but the footer is displaying an error because the variables pageTypeNonce and webpackChunks cannot be evaluated or their values are not being properly retrieved.

